# How to get rid of empty space underneath an image (maybe caused by scaling)?

Tags: html, css

I have 100% width `img` above `div` element. There is little one or two pixel gap between `img` and `div`: [image]

Gap is visible only at some points when image is resizes. So I assume it is some remaining decimal value after aspect ratio calculation presenting itself as empty space. Anyone knows some elegant way how could I get rid of this gap and what could be causing it? (I cannot use background-image as I do not know size of the image.)

(It is not caused by image being inline element as I changed it to `display: block`.)

HTML:

```html
  <div class="parentDiv">
    <img src="src">
    <div>
      some content
    </div>
  </div>
```

CSS:

```css
.parentDiv {
  width: 100%;
}

.parentDiv img {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: Would you make an minimal reproduction example pleasse? [mre]

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
```